# Reading Formatted Text from PowerPoint Programatically

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I use something like this to get the text from a shape inside PowerPoint:

```
s = ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.Shapes("rec1").TextFrame.TextRange.Text
```

However, if the text has bold, underlined, resized (etc) text within the shape (meaning only certain words or phrases inside the shape), the `.Text` property converts it all to plain text.

I am looking to grab the stylized markup (perhaps RTF) of the shape.

I see that if I copy the text (*highlight, right-click, then pick COPY*), and then *PASTE* it into WordPad, it preserves everything. However, I dont see a `.RTFText` property (*or anything similar*) of the `TextRange` that I can access programatically.

Does anyone know how to do this programatically (via VBA I suppose)?

Thanks -

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the only supported method is to automate clipboard access: do a VBA Copy and get the text from the clipboard yourself. Not elegant, and with side effects noticeable for the user, but...

Comment: with a bit of tinkering, I did get this to work by doing the copy(), then reading the rtf contents of the clipboard. Thanks -